# want to assigning 12 digit long number in variable

Tags: java

**Want to assign 12 digits number in a long type variable**
error: integer number too large: 100000000000
long no = 100000000000;

```
long no = 100000000000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat the literal as a long as well using "L" at the end of the number:

```
long no = 100000000000L;
```

Without the literal, the number is treated as an `int`.

Comment: what should I do when I am converting string number in Long int 
ex: long accountNoEntered = Integer.parseInt(accountNoT.getText());
I am taking a string from JTextField

Comment: @SumitKawale you can use `Long.parseLong(String s)`

Answer (score 1):

This is because by default every constant number you're assigning to a variable is seen as an `int`. To make your example work, you need to add an "L" at the end of the number.

```
long no = 10000...L;
```